# error while trying to create DTE2 Interface object with ruby

Tags: ruby, visual-studio, automation, win32ole, envdte

I am trying  to use ruby `win32ole`  lib and  [DTE2 Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte80.dte2.aspx) to control visual studio 8 \

tried this

```
require 'win32ole'
ide = WIN32OLE.new('EnvDTE80.DTE2')
```

and received this error  `unknown OLE server: EnvDTE80.DTE2`

what am I doing wrong, can this work at all ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using the wrong object name,  for visual studio 2008  and opening a solution called MySolution.sln :

```
require 'win32ole'

objDTE = WIN32OLE.new("VisualStudio.DTE.9.0")
objDTE.MainWindow.Visible = true   #make VS window visible
objDTE.UserControl = true;         #set to false to cause VS to shut down when the script ends 
solution = objDTE.Solution
solution.Open("MySolution.sln");
```